# What happens to Firebase anonymous users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to know what will happen to the users of my app that I used anonymous sign in method for them.

The Firebase documentation is really BAD and didn't explain everything and expect developer to find out himself. 
I found in its old version documentation that anonymous session will expires based on the expiration time has been set in Login & Auth tab, but even there didn't mention this means just the session ends or it means that user id will remove also from my app users list or what EXACTLY happened?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895385/delete-firebase-anonymous-users-after-a-while) but it really is not acceptable. The number of anonymous users will grow very very fast if you do a web app and make every thing hard.
I even cannot see the number of my app users in my dashboard!!!!!
So, what should i do? should i develop a dashboard for my data myself or Firebase team should do it? At least for managing users i should have more power than just searching user with their email and when you use custom login you cannot do this also.

Comment: This is an excellent question that I would also like an answer to. I have 1000+ anonymous users stacked up because I can't user email/password with my app. I need anonymous. I have 22 ACTUAL users, yet 1000+ of these dang user IDs.

Answer (score 40):

Anonymous users don't expire, and there isn't currently any automated way to purge them.

Firebase doesn't automatically remove them because it doesn't really know if a user is still storing data linked to that login - only the app creator does.  Imagine if you are playing a puzzle game on your phone, and get to level 100. Then when you go to play level 101 next year, all progress is lost. Firebase can't just assume a user being inactive for a year means that the account can be removed.

There is a couple tools that should help, though.

1) [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) & [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth#authexport) list users.

2) [Linking multiple auth providers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking)

3) [Auth State Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence)

Once you list your users, you can check that each doesn't have any other providers, and hasn't been used recently, doesn't have data stored, and [delete them](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

Better, though, would be to ensure that only one account is created per user.  If you create an anonymous account to help users store data before logging in, you may want to consider prompting them to link a auth provider (like Google or email).  If you link the account, rather than creating a new one, you'll avoid abandoned accounts from active users.

In general, you will also want to make sure to use auth state persistence to ensure that there aren't more accounts than necessary being created. Creating 1 account per new visitor, rather than 1 per time someone repeatedly visits your page, will significantly help keep user growth in check.

Comment: should I refresh the id_token using the refresh token to avoid creating new anonymous users ? Thanks

Answer (score 14):

In my case, I am using the anonymous sign-in method for authentication without the knowledge of the user.
Each time when the user leaves the app, delete the anonymous user by -

```
FirebaseAuth.getinstance().currentuser?.delete()
```

There will be no stacking up of anonymous user with this and limits the number of anonymous user in the app

Comment: This is assuming that the app is actually closed correctly. In the event that the app crashes, those users' anonymous accounts will not be removed.

Comment: I actually landed up here searching the benefit of authenticating a user anonymously. I wish to know in your case what is the advantage of authenticating the user at all?
How is it different from not authenticating the user and keeping it public. (I have a similar req where none of the anonymous user is ever expected to be converted to any other provider. Unable to find any justification for using anonymous authentication)

Comment: if you have an authenticated account (even anonymous ones), then you can take advantage of security rules that require an authenticated account to access the database. That's the only reason.

Answer (score 4):

## 2023 update

Firebase has automatic clean up now.

> If you've upgraded your project to Firebase
> Authentication with Identity Platform, you can enable automatic
> clean-up in the Firebase console. When you enable this feature you
> allow, Firebase to automatically delete anonymous accounts older than
> 30 days. In projects with automatic clean-up enabled, anonymous
> authentication will not count toward usage limits or billing quotas.
>
> Any anonymous accounts created after enabling automatic clean-up might
> be automatically deleted any time after 30 days post-creation.
> Anonymous accounts created before enabling automatic clean-up will be
> eligible for automatic deletion starting 30 days after enabling
> automatic clean-up. If you turn automatic clean-up off, any anonymous
> accounts scheduled to be deleted will remain scheduled to be deleted.
> These accounts do not count toward usage limits or billing quotas. If
> you "upgrade" an anonymous account by linking it to any sign-in
> method, the account will not get automatically deleted. If you want to
> see how many users will be affected before you enable this feature,
> and you've upgraded your project to Firebase Authentication with
> Identity Platform, you can filter by is_anon in Cloud Logging.

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#auto-cleanup)

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing this! I'm curious if this is also applied to "active" anonymous accounts, as in anonymous user who is actively using the app within that 30 days period. It's quite common to see users who continue to use the service without connecting any account especially in mobile apps, and I wouldn't want their account to be suddenly deleted. I read the docs but there's no statement that it counts last active time into the calculation so I assume it would also delete anonymous account that is highly active even on the 29th day?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible **cloud function** for that.
Check: [delete-unused-accounts-cron](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main/delete-unused-accounts-cron)

This function **deletes unused accounts after a certain time**. Which might be also helpfull for nonanonymous users.

If you only want to delete anonymous users or check only for them (for example delete after a different inactive time than normal users) you can identify them by checking:

```js
const inactiveUsers = result.users.filter(
        user => {
            isAnonymous = user.providerData.length == 0;
            //do something when anonymous
        });
```

Comment: The provider id for an anonymous user is "firebase", which results in size of user.providerData > 0, so your "isAnonymous" check won't work I assume.

Answer (score -5):

If you'd like anonymous users to be removed from your user list, you'll have to write a service to do that for you.

Since firebase doesn't provide a way to list registered users, you'll have to make sure you're storing some sort of user list in the database. You can then use the node.js admin sdk to [get user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#get-user), check if the [user is anonymous](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord#provider-data), and find [when the user was created](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserMetadata). For performance reasons, you may wish to store this information in a special area of your database and retrieve it all at once. Once you've identified a stale anonymous user they can be [easily deleted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth#delete-user).

Comment: This is deleting the problem.

Comment: What are you hoping would happen to anonymous users?

Comment: I should be able to manage my users easily, whether it's anonymous or not. For users maybe i can set an expiry time after that delete.

Comment: You'll have to use the [admin API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/) if you're looking for more functionality than what the Firebase console provides.

Comment: Firebase auth already has a "Signed In" value with last signed in timestamp, If a login is inactive for more than x days, delete it