# Firebase anonimous authentication how does it works?

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

The question is - if I use anonymous authentication to provide access to data like in google to those who have a link, will firebase generate trash of users or will it clean them up all the time the session ends?

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous users are not auto-deleted. If the user restarts the app, they will be signed in as the same anonymous user.

If you want to clean up user accounts that haven't been used in a while, see [Delete Firebase anonymous users after a while](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895385/delete-firebase-anonymous-users-after-a-while/38809125)

Comment: Thank you Frank. I thought it is so but haven't found a best practices link.