# Cloud Firestore - how to stop “any user can read your entire database” error email

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have these database security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

all of our DB data is public by design, so we allow everyone to read it.
my question is how can I disable the error emails I keep getting from firebase?

Comment: Depends on what tour database contains. Let’s say you had user details you could only Allow the users to write if their is matches the documents I’d

Comment: @GILO thanks for the comment, I edited the title, I meant that any user can READ the entire db, which is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `match /{document=**} {...` just create a simple rule for every collection:

```
match /users/{document} {
  allow read: if true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers don't help, are you using *anonymous login*? There are a few articles for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth), [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth), etc... That show you how to do that.

**Here is an example:**

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});
```

Keep in mind however that you may have to delete those users once in a while. For example, there is a discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37895385/delete-firebase-anonymous-users-after-a-while) on how to maintain this.